# Laptop for programming

Tags: laptop

I'm searching a laptop, principally for programming and web (YouTube, Twitter...)

Requirements:

- My budget is 550 €
- A minimum of 6GB of ram
- Quad core processor
- No GPU needed
- No OS preference

Comment: Hi! Could you edit your question and put more details? At this moment your question is too broad. Almost every laptop will handle these tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend the [Dell Inspiron 15 5000](http://www.dell.com/us/p/inspiron-15-5555-laptop/pd?oc=dncwvamd6218h&model_id=inspiron-15-5555-laptop)

### Specs

- Quad-core AMD A8-7410 CPU
- Windows 10 Home 64 bit
- 6GB RAM
- 128GB SSD
- No dGPU, uses an APU
- 768p screen

Comment: It look like good, but the sales is only for 2 day and I will buy it after Christmas... Thanks anyway

Comment: @user5537808 Even after the sale, it still meets your budget. $600 = 550EU according to google, anyway